# Ranking in fuzzy match in vespa

Tags: vespa

Looks like while doing fuzzy matching in vespa, ranking is not getting applied to the documents. All the documents have a similar relevance score, which is the score achieved from any one document which is matched completely.

I am getting documents correctly ranked without using any fuzzy match but as soon as I use the fuzzy operator, all documents have the same ranking score.

Ranking expression I am using is:

```
attributeMatch(name).matches*25 + attributeMatch(keywords).matches*3 + attributeMatch(paragraph).matches*2
```

How can we achieve ranking along with fuzzy matching in vespa?

Answer (score 1):

That is correctly observed. The fuzzy query term does not produce any rank-features currently, see https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/24242